# Change UL LI bullet points only in text - Wordpress - CSS

Tags: html, wordpress, css, css-selectors

I wanted to change the style of the bullet points in text on posts and pages, so I've done that with the following CSS style:

```
/* Remove the old bullet points */
ul li { 
  list-style: none;
}
/* Now replace with the new one */
ul li::before {
  color: red;  
  content: "\2022"; 
  font-size: 1.4em; 
  padding-right: 0.5em; 
  position: relative;
  top: 0em; 
}
```

This works, but now it went totally crazy and added the bullet point in front of every `ul li` tag on the page.

I know that I can exclude id's and classes from this like `ul:not(.class) li:not(.class)::before`

but my list exclusion is now growing and I'm most likely going to miss somewhere anyway.

So is there a different way of doing this?

I know that I could manually add the class to the `ul li` tags where I want the new bullets, but I'm trying to avoid doing this manually.

I basically want to change the default bullet style, but only for the bullets that are in content on posts and pages.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @JAK answer is right .. But if you can't get a selector yourself you can Provide the relative HTML code and let's suggest a selector for you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it sounds like you would do well to have a class that wraps the areas of your site where you want this change to take place. For instance:

```
.post ul li { 
  list-style: none;
}

.post ul li::before {
  color: red;  
  content: "\2022"; 
  font-size: 1.4em; 
  padding-right: 0.5em; 
  position: relative;
  top: 0em; 
}
```

You could chain different classes together in the following way:

```
.post ul li,
.page ul li { 
  list-style: none;
}

.post ul li::before,
.page ul li::before {
  color: red;  
  content: "\2022"; 
  font-size: 1.4em; 
  padding-right: 0.5em; 
  position: relative;
  top: 0em; 
}
```

Or perhaps create a rule that specifically targets the lists you want to alter.

Comment: Hey @JAK, yep I've tried that, unfortunately it seem that every post or page uses the exact same class, that is .entry-content

Comment: I'll see if I can add and additional class into the posts template only ..

Comment: To clarify then; you want to target only bullets within posts of a certain type? You will need to find some way to define those parts of your site where you want to make this change. Either by adding a new class into your HTML or with more complex selectors.

Comment: Hi , yes, correct, I've just added a selector into the template of the posts where I want to change the bullets. It actually works the way I wanted now.

Comment: Glad to hear it! It's worth noting that unordered lists can take on a lot of different roles within a webpage and so scoping CSS changes to them should be done carefully. Just make sure the parent selector isn't too broad and you should be fine. :)

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9ADS.png)
WordPress supports the creation of ordered (numbered) and unordered (bullet point) lists in posts and pages. The standard post/page editor facilitates easy creation of lists – simply type the contents of the list (one entry per line), then highlight the entries and click the appropriate button to format as a list.